# Why is PyShp unable to open my .dbf or .shp files?

Tags: python, shapefile, dbf, pyshp

Trying to learn to use Python to map some geographic data by following some tutorial and I can't seem to get them to work. I'm hoping this is just a simple error on my part.

First, the link(s) to the tutorials:

https://towardsdatascience.com/mapping-with-matplotlib-pandas-geopandas-and-basemap-in-python-d11b57ab5dac

https://towardsdatascience.com/mapping-geograph-data-in-python-610a963d2d7f

I am unable to get past the steps using code for the importing of the files.

My code is

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True) 
sns.mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(10,6))

#opening the vector map
shp_path = "C:\\Users\\Jack\\.spyder-py3\\District_Boundary.shp"
#reading the shape file by using reader function of the shape lib
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

len(sf.shapes())
```

My error output is:

```
  File "C:\Users\Jack\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\shapefile.py", line 646, in load
    raise ShapefileException("Unable to open %s.dbf or %s.shp." % (shapeName, shapeName))

ShapefileException: Unable to open C:\Users\Jack\.spyder-py3\District_Boundary.dbf or C:\Users\Jack\.spyder-py3\District_Boundary.shp.
```

Comment: Do the files exist where you think they do? Try `import os` then do `os.path.exists("/your/path")`. If it returns False, then your path is wrong. We have no way of telling if your file is actually there, so this is the first thing to try.

Comment: I can read District_Boundary.shp just fine with pyshp and geopandas.  You've got your path wrong I suggest. Where did you download and unzip [District_Boundary.zip](https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=acb8cb18e7cd45c982086b6ef2bb5a62) to?

Comment: Do you have the dbf and the shx files also in the folder?

Comment: Thanks guys. ID-10T error. Forgot the file name was also the folder name and didn't include it.

Comment: @RichardLaw Nice troubleshooting help. Would you be willing to include your comment as an answer so we can consider this question resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the files exist where you think they do. This is generally part of good script writing: before trying to read a file, assert that it exists.

Here's one possible adaptation of your code, using `assert` to test the return value of `os.path.exists` with your proposed file path as input:

```py
import os

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import shapefile as shp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid", palette="pastel", color_codes=True) 
sns.mpl.rc("figure", figsize=(10,6))

# opening the vector map
shp_path = "C:\\Users\\Jack\\.spyder-py3\\District_Boundary.shp"
assert os.path.exists(shp_path), "Input file does not exist."

# reading the shape file by using reader function of the shape lib
sf = shp.Reader(shp_path)

len(sf.shapes())
```

Now if you run this you will see an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 14, in <module>
AssertionError: Input file does not exist.
```

Incidentally, the original error was also OK. I'd probably not even bother with the assertion. It was telling you that it was unable to read the files it expected to find. That's an expected result when the file doesn't exist.